# Flexslider jQuery Plugin, delay showing the caption

Tags: jquery

I'm using the Flexslider (http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) plugin for a slideshow, and would like the captions to delay before appearing.

I have gotten this far with the initilizating code,

```
 $(window).load(function() {
              $('.flexslider').flexslider({slideshow:false});

            });

$('.slide1caption').css("display","none");
$('.slide1caption').slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
```

I just need the caption portion to reset every time a new slide comes in. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something closer to the code they have on their Advanced use example:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      controlsContainer: ".flex-container",
      after: function(slider) {
         // animate your caption ... 
         // find the item that is the current slide's .slidecaption and animate it
         $('.current-slide').find('.slidecaption').slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
      }
    });
});
```

Just remember, you're going to want to set a long enough delay in each slide to get the caption animation completed before the next one begins!

Comment: Thank you, that set me in the right direction, here's what I came up with. $('.slide1caption').css({ opacity: 0 }).delay(600).animate({opacity: 1, bottom: 50});

  
    $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      controlsContainer: ".flex-container",
      before: function(slider) {
     $('.flex-active-slide').find('.slide1caption').css({ opacity: 0, bottom: -50 });
      },
      after: function(slider) {
      $('.flex-active-slide').find('.slide1caption').delay(400).animate({opacity: 1,bottom: '50'});}
    });